# Cancel a single Webworker event

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is it possible to cancel the handling of a single action invoked by `worker.postMessage(..)` ?
There is the `worker.terminate()` method, but it cancels any waiting event. Also it seems to render the whole worker dead, as it doesn't react to further `postMessage` calls.

On the other hand, it seems useless to create a new `Worker` for every task, if they operate on a large amount of common data, that have to be traversed from `Worker` to `Worker` via the main script, cloning the whole data everytime.

Comment: It seems that it is impossible by design. The reason could be that a canceled webworker can terminate at any internal state thus leaving it's data in undefined state. By killing the whole webworker, it is impossible to access those data. If another event could run the web worker again, it would get access to the bad state again.

Answer (score 6):

It's true that `worker.terminate()` kills the thread. As there's a decent amount of memory and CPU overhead associated with WebWorkers, that fact can be expensive.

The way to handle the canceling of single events would to host some sort of controller logic inside of your `postMessage` callback. Your worker can have state, so you'd have to keep track of that state internally and stop or start processes using that semaphore.

One way might be to created a shared Worker, which can even be used across tabs, and then have that shared worker handle spinning off your other threads where necessary.

Comment: So I need to inject ANY code that possibly run some time with an stop condition switch? That would mean the modification of any loop which run cylces depend on given input data for example, even 3rd party library code. I think shared Workers doesn't change anything either. 'Spinning off other threads' means copying of the whole internal data again, which made up my primary problem.

Answer (score 1):

you’ll need to write the code in your worker if flag x is set via postmessage to ’pause’ specific processing jobs until via postmessage the greenlight is given, the you need to give your code a kickstart to start processing again.

to bad javascript doesn’t support pointers, otherwiseyou wouldn’t have the memory problem.

Comment: I think the problem is not of having no 'pointers' but of the way the `Worker`s are designed: They don't share anything with another thread except the message queue of `postMessage`. So they circumvent a large amount of problems that other languages and VMs need to take care off.

Comment: Thank you @JanPöschko for the acknowledgement :-D

Comment: You're welcome. :) If you explain your answer a little better (maybe with some code sample?) people might understand it better. And your final sentence is certainly a bit far-fetched. (1. Most things are in fact treated by reference in JavaScript. 2. Sharing memory with workers is disabled by design.)

Comment: I know, I only have one rule, I don't write long code for others if I don't get anything back for it. And this would involve at least 5 minutes of coding/typing, which is too much of my valuable time... I know they are by pointers, but you don't control where or how it is stored. It may be stored by reference, but when sharing with a worker, it is duplicated. You can't bypass the worker confines and access memory directly via a pointer. That is what I meant.

Comment: Absolutely understandable. What I meant is that it is not "too bad" this way - it _has_ to be this way or things could go terribly wrong with raw pointers to shared memory among workers.